# get; set; vs get; private set;

Tags: c#, getter-setter

I am just wondering, functionally, what is the difference between:

```
private int var {get; set;}
```

and

```
public int var {get; private set;}
```

Also, why does

```
private int var {get; set;}
```

return an error?

I am new to using getters and setters.

Comment: `private int var {get; set;}` doesn't return an error for me. Can you provide code that shows the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between the two is that

```cs
private int var {get; set;}
```

will not allow other classes to access and modify the value of var, while

```cs
public int var {get; private set;}
```

will only allow other classes to access the value of var, but not modify it.

The reason why

```cs
private int var {get; set;}
```

returns an error is because you are trying to set the value of var to a private field. In order to set the value of var, you need to use the public setter.

Comment: You got the first one wrong. `private int var {get; set;}` does ***not*** allow other classes to access it.

Comment: @Enigmativity Small typo, fixed

Answer (score 0):

`public int var { get; set; }` is like:

```cs
public class Var {
    private int var;

    public int Get() { return var; }
    public void Set(int var) { this.var = var; }
}
```

if you define `public int var { get; private set; }`, it will be like:

```cs
public class Var {
    private int var;

    public int Get() { return var; }
    private void Set(int var) { this.var = var; }
}
```

So getter and setter is like call `Get()` or `Set()` function when you get or set `var`:

```cs
Var v = new Var();

// like v.Set(1);
// if Set() is private, it will returns error.
v.var = 1;

// like Console.log(v.Get());
Console.log(v.var);
```

It just a analogy, maybe you could see about [properties document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) to know more.